# CakePHP: Retrieving data

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I'm stuck in retrieving some sort of data in my view. I have to list information of a certain "Job", which has different attributes already stored in the database.
For example, I'd like to get the field of 'weighting' listed. 
The `debug($this->viewVars)` prints me this (which represents what's stored in the DB):

```
'JobValues' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'yearly_job_id' => '1',
                'institution_type_id' => '1',
                'norm_rate' => '5',
                'weighting' => '5.00',
                'standard_value' => '5.00',
                'education_weeks' => '5.0',
                'group_distribution' => '0.50',
                'YearlyJob' => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'year_id' => '1',
                    'job_id' => '1',
                    'full_time_jobs_needed' => true,
                    'education_count_needed' => true,
                    'is_care' => true
                ),
```

Normally I would just print this: `echo([JobValue][weighting]);`, but there is a number in between, so `echo([JobValue][1][weighting]);` won't lead to success. What could I implement in my view (or model)? Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: because you have use find all I think into your controller

Comment: Either use `find('first'...)` or just `echo $foo['JobValues'][0]['weighting'];`. Needs more information to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's best to include/add the code inside your controller to your question, especially the part where you retrieve the data using your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing out the data, if there's only one top level of array, just remove it. `print_r(array_shift($foo['JobValues']['weighting']));`

If there are multiple arrays on the same level, you need to do a `foreach` to iterate into each one of the record.